# How to manage an HDInsight cluster through the portal?

Tags: azure, hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I recently started working on with the `Windows Azure` and `HDInsight`, in order to do some `MapReduce` jobs. What I wanted to know is, is it possible to pause or stop the running cluster whenever not necessary through the `Azure Management Portal`?

I tried for options to stop or pause, but couldn't find any. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*HDInsight* does not support statuses other than *Running* and *Stopped*, meaning that a cluster cannot be set on a *Pause* or *Idle* state, unlike other cloud providers. You can find a request to add this feature [here](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217335-hdinsight/suggestions/5663773-start-stop-cluster-hdinsight), if you are interested.

Answering to your other question, managing the *HDInsight* through the management portal is quite straightforward. There is a complete interface section dedicated to the management of clusters.

I assume you have already performed the necessary steps in order to create a new *HDInsight* cluster, which are:

- Create a microsoft account
- Create a subscription plan
- [Create a storage account](http://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/)

The image below shows how a cluster can be created in two simple steps:

> Step 1: create a new element

[image: Create a new element]

> Step 2: introduce necessary parameters for the cluster

[image]

After a *relatively* short boot time, a new cluster will be listed on the *HDInsight* panel, which you can then administer and, after finishing the necessary jobs, delete if necessary.

[image]

Comment: I need to know another small thing in here, so if it keeps on running, will it be billed? If so what should I do in order to use it only when i need?

Comment: Yes, it will be billed as long as you have a running cluster. Like I said, a cluster cannot be stopped to reuse it later; instead, you must *kill* and re-*create* the cluster everytime you need to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Another clarification. If you click and go within your cluster, you'll find a configuration option, what would happen if i turn on and off the hadoop services? Still will it be the same? ie: will it be billed?

Comment: Again, it will be billed as long as you have a running cluster, despite you having the services turned *on* or *off*. Unfortunately, there is not a way, at this moment, to do what you and many other people (including me) want to do. I would even adventure myself to say that many people has changed the cloud provider due to this - in my opinion - *huge* lack.